# How do I produce only an object file (*.o) from a CMake build target?

Tags: cmake, build-process, object-files

I'm trying to build an object file using CMake, but I can't seem to get CMake to build something other than a complete executable. I'm basically looking for the result of the following compilation (the result will be loaded on a VxWorks target and linked then):

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c src/object.c
```

I've tried changing the `OUTPUT_NAME` property of the target, but that doesn't seem to help, either.

I think I could work around this by using a custom command, but that seems like I'm also working around the nice things that CMake provides.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am wondering why you want the object-file. Is it not possible to build a static lib with CMake? If necessary, a static lib from only one source file? Alternatively you could try to link the executable anyway and "re-use" the generated object-files

Comment: @Andre One advantage would be to work on fixing compile errors for a single file when you know there are also compile errors elsewhere in the project (for instance if you're working closely with another developer on code that's not yet ready for general consumption) without needing to edit `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Answer (score 8):

This answer was given to me in the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/042284.html) and it worked like a charm:

Look at the following `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cpo` script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
d=$1; shift
while [ "$1" != "--" ]; do
  cp $1 $d/$(basename $1); shift
done
```

Now, look at the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(CPO C) 
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/f.c "void f(void){}\n")
ADD_LIBRARY(f SHARED f.c)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(f PROPERTIES RULE_LAUNCH_LINK
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cpo ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} <OBJECTS> --"
)
```

The launch script "cpo" makes the target "f" produce object files in
the directory passed in as the first parameter instead of a library;
everything else should be business as usual. The key is the script's
access to the `<OBJECTS>` placeholder, so it can operate on the object
files while the actual link command after the "--" is ignored. That
way, you can use all of CMake's capabilities for the compilation and
intercept right before linking takes place. IMO, that's a quite clean
solution which should be easily adaptable to your needs; the downside
is that the use of `RULE_LAUNCH_LINK` is limited to `Makefile` generators.

Comment: Cool solution right to the point where it is limited to Makefile generators

Answer (score 5):

Since CMake 3.1, CMake has had the ability to create [Object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries):

> The `OBJECT` library type defines a non-archival collection of object files resulting from compiling the given source files.

To *only* create the object file (no library or executable), use this `OBJECT` keyword with the [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) command:

```
# This will create object.c.o (or object.c.obj on Windows) when built.
add_library(MyObj OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/object.c)
```

You can later reference the object file(s) to be compiled into other libraries or executables:

```
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyObj> MyClass1.cpp Helpers.cpp)
```

Comment: Why won't `add_library(MyLibrary STATIC MyObj MyClass1.cpp Helpers.cpp)` work?

Comment: @einpoklum The arguments for `add_library` following the `STATIC` keyword (or other library type keyword) should be *source* files. Because `MyObj` is not a source file, but a target name, we must tell CMake about this special case by referencing it with `TARGET_OBJECTS`.

Comment: I was under the mistaken impression that files are constitute targets.

Answer (score 2):

I would go the custom command path. Remember you can still use those object files for compilation with CMake latter if you set the GENERATED and EXTERNAL_OBJECT source file properties.