# How do I tell CMake to compile source files without linking?

Tags: gcc, compilation, cmake

The title says it all. I want a way equivalent to adding the "-c" flag in GCC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5462006/400303

Comment: Making a custom make script? That just seems completely and utterly unnecessarily over the top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I produce only an object file (\*.o) from a CMake build target?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765222/how-do-i-produce-only-an-object-file-o-from-a-cmake-build-target)

Answer (score 1):

Referred questions and answers look out of date (and strange some time).
Nowadays CMake is capable to do exactly what you want. All that you need is to add an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html#object-libraries).